# Estimate Q-Table online with a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, q-learning

When i use Q-Table for save state-action in reinforcement learning, some state never (or rarely) happen and state-action value remain zero until max-iteration so i decide to estimate Q-Table online with a neural network instead of using Q-Table.

Which type of neural networks can estimate this kind of problem more accurate and does this solution help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use Localy Weighted Regression(LWR) as function approximation
and simply replace table with this function